# Redefining <leader> to previous mappings in vim

Tags: vim

In vim `:help leader` says that changing `<leader>` after the moment that a mapping is defined does not change the mapping. 
So how can I update my already mapping that used `<leader>` with a new value of `<leader>`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Herbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76434/herbert-sitz) gave the right answer: the `<leader>` shall be defined in the .vimrc. We don't want a completely cumbersome procedure to change `<leader>` on the fly. It's the same with `<plug>`-mappings.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to execute the mapping command again. If the mapping comes from a vimscript file, you will need to reload (`:source`) it.

I guess it is useful because you won't need to edit mappings on vimcscripts that use `<leader>`

Comment: What you describe may seem like a pain.  As a practical matter, though, if someone decides they'd prefer to have a different leader character they will define it in their vimrc file so it gets assigned on vim startup prior to any mappings getting executed.  So the need to reissue mappings would occur only in limited situation where you want to redefine leader only temporarily.  Even then setting the new leader character in vimrc and restarting vim is probably best solution.

Comment: Note how a `:mks! ~/eject.vim` will save the current vim state; so if you restart vim with `vim -S ~/eject.vim` you'll be exactly where you left off